# Calculating weighted average from my dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, data-science

I am trying to calculate the weighted average of amount of times a social media post was made on a given weekday between 2009- 2018.

This is the code I have:

```
weight = fb_posts2[fb_posts2['title']=='status'].groupby('year',as_index=False).apply(lambda x: (x.count())/x.sum())
```

What i am trying to do is to groupby year and weekday, count the number of time each weekday has occurred in a year and divide that by the total number of posts in each year. The idea is to return a dataframe with a  weighted average of how many times each weekday occurred between 2009 and 2018.

This is a sample of the dataframe I am interacting with:
[image: Dataframe]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.value_counts()` with the normalize argument, grouping only on year.

#### Sample Data

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(123)
df = pd.DataFrame({'year': np.random.choice([2010, 2011], 1000),
                   'weekday': np.random.choice(list('abcdefg'), 1000),
                   'val': np.random.normal(1, 10, 1000)})
```

#### Code:

```
df.groupby('year').weekday.value_counts(normalize=True)
```

#### Output:

```
year  weekday
2010  d          0.152083
      f          0.147917
      g          0.147917
      c          0.143750
      e          0.139583
      b          0.137500
      a          0.131250
2011  d          0.182692
      a          0.163462
      e          0.153846
      b          0.148077
      c          0.128846
      f          0.111538
      g          0.111538
Name: weekday, dtype: float64
```